# EqualToString not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an array that contain different objects, i need to find one with NSString property of specific text. I wonder why following not work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.arrValues.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"arr value VM class %@", [self.arrValues[i] class]);
    id val = self.arrValues[i];
    if ([val  respondsToSelector:@selector(title)]){

        NSLog(@"ob-class-%@", [self.arrValues[i] class]);
        SideMenuItemVM *obj = self.arrValues[i];
        NSLog(@"title %@", obj.title);
        if ([obj.title isEqualToString:@"Мероприятия"]){
            NSLog(@"Got it");
        } 
    } 
}
```

it does output  `title Мероприятия`, but not the second NSLog. What did i miss?

arr value VM class output class of `SideMenuItemVM`, which does contain property  `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title`;

So, output here look like

```
2016-08-23 11:19:33.420 project[56065:18112626] ob-class-SideMenuItemVM
2016-08-23 11:19:33.420 project[56065:18112626] title Мероприятия
```

Comment: maybe obj.title has some whitespaces as prefix or suffix

Comment: maybe use `containsString` is better

Comment: Why test for `title` selector and then cast to a particular class type?  Why not just use `isKindOfClass` instead of `respondsToSelector`?  Also we need to see the list of array elements to see where you went wrong.

Comment: You may want to pass though NSData (and check if they are equal) to check/point out if there is some invisible character.

Comment: @Droppy because value may not have property called title, therefore it will through an exception. Is kind of class could work also, but i guess logic is the same. I update question in a moment.

Comment: Forget about about casting then and just use `[val title]` instead of `obj.title`.  That will compile and work with the selector test.

Comment: @Droppy unfortunately if ([[val title] isEqualToString:@"Мероприятия"]){
                NSLog(@"got value");
            } also has no effect.

Comment: Could you check that your title is really a NSString ? Please, do a  `NSLog(@"title-class-%@", [obj.title class]);` (just to be perfectly sure !)

Comment: Also when logging, use quotes to make spaces more obvious `NSLog(@"title '%@'", [val title]);`.  Note I did not say my previous comments would solve your problem, however your code would be better (shorter and more consistent).

Comment: @JulienQuere yes i tried and it is output title class __NSCFString

Comment: @Larme, Julien Quere, Droppy thank you, if you interested in what is going on here i answer my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone face similar problem, i find the answer, thanks for help i provided in comments. After i quote my NSLog statement, i find something odd. String output from             `NSLog(@"title '%@'", obj.title);`
 look like:`2016-08-23 11:45:22.372 project[67747:18256287] TITl 'Мероприятия`
'

So, it is actually a new line in here, i have no idea why. Simple

```
  if ([obj.title containsString:@"Мероприятия"]){
                NSLog(@"got value");
   }
```

Solve this issue.

Comment: Be aware that this can actually give you false-positives. Like if the title is "XМероприятияX" `containsString` will return true. You might in stead consider removing any leading and trailing whitespace by using `[obj.title stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]` and then call `isEqualToString`.